# How to know if interrupts are disabled?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Is there any way (or a useful function) to know whether interrupts are disabled or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `irqs_disabled()` function:

```
#include <linux/irqflags.h>

int i = irqs_disabled();
```