# How can I check a specific IRQ is disabled in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt

I have a question about IRQ in Linux kernel. I enable a IRQ using `request_threaded_irq()`. But sometimes we need to disable IRQ using `disable_irq()`. Depending on the situation, it may be necessary to enable it again. Can I check a specific IRQ is already enabled before enable IRQ? To prevent enable again. Is there any API to check a specific IRQ is enabled or disabled?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know if interrupts are disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049049/how-to-know-if-interrupts-are-disabled)

Comment: No. I want to know a certain irq is disabled.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and update your requirements? As currently stated, I see no evidence that you want to check only a specific interrupt.

Comment: First of all, you need to get the idea that device IRQ can be disabled on the side of the *device* and/or on the side of *CPU* (interrupt controller). Second, the `disable_irq()` and `enable_irq()` are **nested**. So, why do you need that check? What for?

Answer (score 0):

Current Linux kernel doesn't provide this function, but you can provide your own in your downstream kernel like:

```c
modified   include/linux/interrupt.h
@@ -244,6 +244,7 @@ bool irq_has_action(unsigned int irq);
 extern void disable_irq_nosync(unsigned int irq);
 extern bool disable_hardirq(unsigned int irq);
 extern void disable_irq(unsigned int irq);
+extern int irq_state_disabled(unsigned int irq);
 extern void disable_percpu_irq(unsigned int irq);
 extern void enable_irq(unsigned int irq);
 extern void enable_percpu_irq(unsigned int irq, unsigned int type);
modified   kernel/irq/manage.c
@@ -704,6 +704,22 @@ static int __disable_irq_nosync(unsigned int irq)
         return 0;
 }

+int irq_state_disabled(unsigned int irq)
+{
+        unsigned long flags;
+        bool ret;
+        struct irq_desc *desc =
+                irq_get_desc_buslock(irq, &flags, IRQ_GET_DESC_CHECK_GLOBAL);
+
+        if (!desc)
+                return -EINVAL;
+
+        ret = irqd_irq_disabled(&desc->irq_data);
+        irq_put_desc_busunlock(desc, flags);
+        return ret;
+}
+EXPORT_SYMBOL(irq_state_disabled);
```

Comment: It's not needed and this is not a (full / correct) answer.

Comment: @0andriy I agree with you that this is not needed. But can you tell me what's go wrong with the function? I tested it locally and it works correctly.

Comment: I haven't said that anything is wrong with the _function_.